# How do you count occurrences in multiple columns and order results by calculation of counted columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count occurrences in multiple columns and then output the results and order them based on a calculation.

Count how many times a killer_uid has occurred. Then count how many times their ID occurs in victim_uid. Then output the results based on the count of killer_uid / victim_uid. Please see example tables and desired output below.

```
Table = kill_feed
+------------+------------+
| killer_uid | victim_uid |
+------------+------------+
|          1 |          2 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          2 |          3 |
|          2 |          1 |
|          2 |          1 |
|          1 |          1 |
+------------+------------+
```

Desired Output:
killer_uid as player_id, 
count instances of killer_uid AS player_kills and victim_uid AS player_deaths,
then divide player_kills / player_deaths (return 0 if divide by 0) and order by those results DESC.

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| player_id | player_kills | player_deaths |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         2 |            4 |             1 | 
|         1 |            2 |             3 | 
|         3 |            0 |             2 | 
+-----------+--------------+---------------+

Order by player_kills / player_deaths
1st = 2 since 4/1 = 4
2nd = 1 since 2/3 = 0.66
3rd = 3 since 0/2 = 0
```

The statement I have tried using but throws a syntax error.

```
SELECT killer_uid as player_id, 
       Count(killer_uid) AS player_kills, 
       Count(victim_uid) AS player_deaths 
FROM   kill_feed
GROUP  BY player_id 
ORDER  BY player_kills / player_deaths DESC
```

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which may prove problematic in due course.

Comment: And surely "*2*/3"

Comment: Primary key exists as `id` (like your example below). Also fixed my 2/3 typo.

Comment: So, you have your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,killer_uid INT NOT NULL
,victim_uid INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (killer_uid,victim_uid) VALUES
(1,2),
(2,3),
(2,3),
(2,1),
(2,1),
(1,1);


SELECT player_id
     , SUM(x) player_kills
     , SUM(y) player_deaths
  FROM
     ( SELECT killer_uid player_id
            , 1 x
            , 0 y
         FROM my_table
        UNION ALL
       SELECT victim_uid
            , 0
            , 1
         FROM my_table
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY player_id
 ORDER
    BY COALESCE(SUM(x)/SUM(y),SUM(x)) DESC;
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
| player_id | player_kills | player_deaths |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
|         2 |            4 |             1 |
|         1 |            2 |             3 |
|         3 |            0 |             2 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: aren't you forgetting `AS` ? or is it just unnecessary ?

Comment: @Damien Ah - it cannot use that alias. Use `ORDER BY SUM(x)/SUM(y)` instead - I'll edit to make my meaning clearer...

Comment: @Strawberry `ORDER BY` does not appear to be working correctly. The output order should be player_id `2` (4/1 = 4), `1` (2/3 = 0.66), `3` (0/2 = 0). The output was not ordered by the calculations supplied / expected. Sorry, I removed and updated my comment the moment you left your comment reply.

Comment: @Strawberry Sum appears to be the way to go. Thank you! Would the following adjustments work for players who have kills and no deaths, to keep them ordered correctly? `SUM(player_kills * 1) / SUM(player_deaths * 1)`  Say a player has 3 kills and 0 deaths. Dividing 3 / 0 = 0. How would I keep the result 3?

Comment: @Damien You could use `COALESCE(SUM(x)/SUM(y),SUM(x))`

Comment: @Strawberry Works perfectly. I will have to do some research as to how this all works next. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's more than one way to skin this particular cat, and maybe another method could make better use of indexes, but to me this method seemed fairly intuitive.